# Refresh Master page of Android Master/Detail Flow from the detail part

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-listfragment

I have a Master/Detail Activity in my Android Application. The Master part shows a list of 10 items. On the detail part of each item there is a Button which can be used to delete that item from the list. Content of My list is from an ArrayList. I could delete any item from the ArrayList, but I am not able to update the master part.

How can I do it? Thanks in Advance for your replies.

Comment: Having not posted your problem code all I can suggest at the moment is to see notifyDataSetChanged() in the ArrayAdapter class: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had done the research and solved the issue. The solution is as follows.

1. Create an interface in the detail fragment class and implement it in the parent activity.
2. Use this interface to update the master list through `notifyDataSetChanged()` function of the adapter.

Comment: please refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11594397/java-using-an-interface-as-a-callback?answertab=active#tab-top